# Excel: Generar mismas referencias de una hoja a otra hoja en una misma tabla

Tags: excel

Tengo datos de una ficha en nombre_hoja_1 y estos están referenciados en una tabla, quiero replicar esta hoja y replicar a su vez las referencias a esta hoja en un tabla que se extiende descendentemente. Estas son las referencias en mi tabla:

```
='nombre_hoja_1'!C14   ='nombre_hoja_1'!C46
```

Lo que pretendo conseguir es generar las mismas referencias a celdas pero de otra hoja, mi tabla tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
 ='nombre_hoja_1'!C14    ='nombre_hoja_1'!C46
 ='nombre_hoja_2'!C14    ='nombre_hoja_2'!C46
 ='nombre_hoja_3'!C14    ='nombre_hoja_3'!C46
 ='nombre_hoja_4'!C14    ='nombre_hoja_4'!C46
```

Lo único que he conseguido hasta ahora arrastrando es lo siguiente:

```
 ='nombre_hoja_1'!C14    ='nombre_hoja_1'!C46
 ='nombre_hoja_1'!C15    ='nombre_hoja_1'!C47
 ='nombre_hoja_1'!C16    ='nombre_hoja_1'!C48
 ='nombre_hoja_1'!C17    ='nombre_hoja_1'!C49
```

Cómo puedo conseguir el resultado esperado? Una macros? un listado, alguna función específica y cómo lo hago?

Muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloca el nombre de la hoja en la celda M1, y la celda que quieres referenciar de esa hoja es C5.

```
M1 = nombre_hoja
```

en la hoja 'nombre_hoja' quiero seleccionar la celda C5:

```
=INDIRECTO("'"&M1&"'!C5")
```

También te servirá:
https://www.ionos.es/digitalguide/online-marketing/vender-en-internet/excel-funcion-indirecto/